# Rotate multi line xlabels for boxplot in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to make a boxplot with rotated xlabels. For a simple case this works:

```matlab
SCAgroups = [1, 1, 2];
SCAgroups2 = {'a', 'b', 'a'};
fH = figure();
aH = axes(fH);
boxplot(aH, CVval, SCAgroups);
xtickangle(aH, 90);
```

[image: Rotated Xlabels]

Now I have 2 labels to group the data:

```matlab
SCAgroups = [1, 1, 2];
SCAgroups2 = {'a', 'b', 'a'};
fH = figure();
aH = axes(fH);
boxplot(aH, CVval, {SCAgroups, SCAgroups2});
xtickangle(aH, 90);
```

[image: Rotation does not work]

How to get rotated Xlabels when the labels are multi-line?

Comment: Well, in the second case, those aren't really XTickLabels. Check: `get(gca,'XTickLabels')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a boxplot parameter *'LabelOrientation'* for this:

```
SCAgroups = [1, 1, 2];
SCAgroups2 = {'a', 'b', 'a'};
fH = figure();
aH = axes(fH);
boxplot(aH, rand(2,3), {SCAgroups, SCAgroups2},'LabelOrientation','inline');
```

[image]